# SQL - extract column from subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm working on a database meant for auctions and I would like get the id of all the winning bids. The hard part is extracting it from a subquery that returns 2 columns: the id and the amount. 
It looks something like this:
 `SELECT id FROM Bid WHERE id IN (Select ID,max(amount) FROM Bid group by bid.idAuction)`

Can I somehow extract just one column from the subquery? Any other sugestions to do this task are helpfull too.

Thank you!

Comment: can you share some dataset with what you want to see? Is there a possibility for max value to occur more than once? What DB engine is that?

Comment: So why use a sub query... use a inline query and a join instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is close, but you need a *correlated subquery* to make this work:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM Bid b
WHERE b.amount = (SELECT max(amount)
                  FROM Bid b2 
                  WHERE b2.idAuction = b.idAuction
                 );
```

Comment: This is exactly the query i've been looking for. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, maxBid.MAmount, Bid.Amount
FROM Bid 
INNER JOIN (Select ID,max(amount) mamount FROM Bid group by bid.idAuction) MaxBid
 on MaxBid.ID = Bid.ID
```

RDBMS and SQL operate most effectively in SET based operations.  So in this case we generate a set based on ID and max bid.  We then join it back to the base set so that only the max bids are treturned.

Comment: Your suggestion led me to another viable solution
`SELECT b1.id, b1.Amount
FROM Bid b1
INNER JOIN (Select b2.idAuction as "Auc",max(b2.amount) as "MAmount" FROM Bid b2 group by b2.idAuction) MaxBid
 on (MaxBid.MAmount=b1.Amount and b1.idAuction=MaxBid.Auc)`

This does the trick! Thank you for your help. Sorry I can't vote up but I don't have 15 rep :(

Comment: From the two answers I think the first one is a little more easier, however I now better understand this Inner Join with sets.